# Graphics jump after first frame of multiframe

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

I am trying to create a countdown timer for my lectures. Everything works fine, except small stretch after the first frame of the multiframe. Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\def\R{1cm} % radius
\newcommand{\timer}[1]{% input = number of second
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\Nseconds{#1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\Nframes{\Nseconds+1}
    \multiframe{\Nframes}{i=0+1}{%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\Nseconds{#1} % dont know why it is necessary to recalculate
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\Nframes{\Nseconds+1} % -//-
        \pgfmathsetmacro\dT{360/\Nseconds} % one time step
        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{90+(\i*\dT)} % angle of already spent time
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\y{\Nseconds-\i} % remaining time
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect]
            % background color
            \filldraw[fill=red, draw = none, line width = 3pt] (0,0) circle [radius=\R];
            % white color of spent time
            \filldraw[fill opacity=0.5,fill=white,draw = none] (0,0) -- (0, \R) arc (90:\x:\R) -- cycle;
            % border circle
            \draw[draw = black, line width = 3pt] (0,0) circle [radius=\R];
            % small ticks
            \foreach \angle in {60,30,...,-270}\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:0.9*\R) -- (\angle:\R);
            % large ticks
            \foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}\draw[line width=2pt] (\angle:0.8*\R) -- (\angle:\R);
            % remaining time
            \node[font=\Large] at (0, 0) {\y};%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
    \end{animateinline}
}

\begin{document}
\timer{90}
\end{document}
```

I have three questions:
1) How to avoid this "jump"?
2) Why is not the size of the document square?
3) What causes white spaces at the left and right sides of the picture?

Answer (score 1):

1. TikZ calculates the size of `tikzpicture` from its content, which may differ from frame to frame. Therefore, enforce a common bounding box for all frames: `\useasboundingbox ...`
2. (& 3) A lot of spurious white space is introduced before and after the animation frames due the lines containing `\pgfmath...` whose endings have not been properly commented.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\def\R{1cm} % radius
\newcommand{\timer}[1]{% input = number of second
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\Nseconds{#1}%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\Nframes{\Nseconds+1}%
    \multiframe{\Nframes}{i=0+1}{%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\Nseconds{#1}% dont know why it is necessary to recalculate
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\Nframes{\Nseconds+1}% -//-
        \pgfmathsetmacro\dT{360/\Nseconds}% one time step
        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{90+(\i*\dT)}% angle of already spent time
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\y{\Nseconds-\i}% remaining time
        \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect]
            \useasboundingbox [draw = black, line width = 3pt] (0,0) circle [radius=\R];
            % background color
            \filldraw[fill=red, draw = none, line width = 3pt] (0,0) circle [radius=\R];
            % white color of spent time
            \filldraw[fill opacity=0.5,fill=white,draw = none] (0,0) -- (0, \R) arc (90:\x:\R) -- cycle;
            % border circle
            \draw[draw = black, line width = 3pt] (0,0) circle [radius=\R];
            % small ticks
            \foreach \angle in {60,30,...,-270}\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:0.9*\R) -- (\angle:\R);
            % large ticks
            \foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}\draw[line width=2pt] (\angle:0.8*\R) -- (\angle:\R);
            % remaining time
            \node[font=\Large] at (0, 0) {\y};%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
    \end{animateinline}% <== line terminated with `%'
}

\begin{document}
\timer{90}
\end{document}
```